# How can I add two strokes to a same D3 element using style attribute?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg, stroke

- I want to add two strokes of two different colors around d3 circle.
- I have code for adding blue colored stroke around the circle. I want to edit this stroke, so that I may have two different strokes (say red and blue) around circle.
- I need to use setting up of stroke using style only.

  ```
  svg.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function (d) {
      return (5);
  }).style("stroke", function (d, i) {            
          return "blue";          
  })
  ```

Comment: Draw 2 circles one for each stroke.

Comment: @RobertLongson Probably the easiest way around, but considering *"using style only"* I don't this is what the author is after.

Comment: You could achieve it with one circle using radial gradients but its a good deal more complicated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Reading the title, one thinks that you want two strokes, an outer one and an inner one, in a given circle. But reading your second point ("*I want to edit this stroke, so that I may have two different strokes*") it seems to me that you want the ability of changing the stroke from blue to red (depending on a condition, for instance)... is that correct? You mean "two strokes at the same time" or just "two different strokes"? Can you clarify your desired outcome?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear, but I want two strokes at the same time.